# Is there anyway to run Ubuntu and Windows 10 at the same time (no VM)

Tags: dual-boot

I'm wanting to run Linux and Windows 10 at the same time and just switch between desktops with a hotkey or something and I was wondering if there was any way to do it. I've seen it before with a MacOS and windows but can't, unfortunately,  can't find any videos for examples

Comment: There is the Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10.  I don't know if that is what you are thinking.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide

Comment: What you saw was probably a Windows VM running on a macOS host.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. but you need two computers. If you want to run two OS's on a single computer, you need to use some type of virtualization technology (VMware, virtual box, grub, xen hypervisor, whatever) and then it's simple to set up a 'hotkey' to switch between, ESPECIALLY if you go the hypervisor route.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to run two operating systems on the same machine because they both require exclusive control over the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that may meet your needs:

Virtualbox 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Will allow a Ubuntu Virtual Machine to run within Windows 10, which can be configured to hoykey swap from Windows 10 (base install) to Ubuntu (installed on VM). Virtual box can also be configured to share access to the Windows 10 file system, and hardware, within the Ubuntu VM

Hyper-V, the Microsoft VM, isn't included in Windows 10 Home, requires pro edition upgrade, and conflicts with other VM software.

If your goal is to have access to parts of Ubuntu available to the Windows 10 install, I suggest you look at:

Bash on Ubuntu on Windows
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about